# After login shows blank page instead of correct layout. Android

Tags: android

When the user logs into the app it than displays a blank white screen instead of the correct page, when i close and reopen the app it does display the correct layout. This is how I'm deciding which layout gets used. I'm not sure if this matters but in the `manifest` I set up the `LoginActivity.java` as a regular activity, and I put it underneath the `MainActivity.java` declaration.
All the code below is inside the onCreate method for each of the clases I mention below.

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
    android:label="Login"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

```
//MainActivity.java. The user gets saved to SharedPreferences when they 
//login, here it checks if they are logged in to see which layout gets 
//displayed.

User user = SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(MainActivity.this);

if (user.getToken() == null) {
    Intent login = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(login);
} else {
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     buildMain();
}

//LoginActivity.java. Here I send the username, password to the server to 
//login and receive the user token (api authentication), if the response is
//successful I save all the user stuff to SharedPreferences and check to see 
//if it was saved in order to finish the activity.

if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    User user = response.body();
    SharedPreferencesHelper.setUser(LoginActivity.this, user);
    User current = SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(LoginActivity.this);

    if (current.getToken() != null) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

These are just the snippets of code where the action happens, the actual code is a lot longer but I didn't think the other stuff was super relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a splash screen, you should check if the user is logged in on the splash screen.

An example, on the onCreate method of the splash screen you place the following code

```
User user = SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(SplashScreen.this);    
if (user.getToken() == null) {
    Intent login = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(login);

} else {
    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(mainActivity);
    finish();  // To remove splash screen from the backstack
}
```

Then on the login activity

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
    User user = response.body();
    SharedPreferencesHelper.setUser(LoginActivity.this, user);
    User current = SharedPreferencesHelper.getUser(LoginActivity.this);

    if (current.getToken() != null) {
        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainActivity);
        finish();  // To remove login from the backstack
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed this tutorial and use the first method, so I can't do what you're suggesting https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565